# Wrapper for a callback from a weak poitner

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Quite often I use the following approach for a callback:

```
scheduleCallback(std::function<void()> callback);

class MyClass
{

void test()
{
    ...
    scheduleCallback([weakPtr{weak_from_this()}](){
        if (auto sharedPtr = weakPtr.lock())
            sharedPtr->someFunction();
    });
}
void someFunction();
}
```

to avoid writing manually that boilerplate code each time I wrote a `weak_function` wrapper that does that automatically:

```
template<typename C, typename... Args>
constexpr std::function<void(Args...)> weak_function(std::weak_ptr<C> weakPtr, void (C::*mf)(Args...))
{
    return [weakPtr, mf](Args&&... args) {
        if (auto ptr = weakPtr.lock())
            return (*ptr.*mf)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };
}
```

So, now the code becomes easier to read:

```
scheduleCallback(weak_function(weak_from_this(), &MyClass::someFunction));
```

Effectively, the idea is to lock weak ptr first and if it's locked only then call the member function on the locked ptr.
This also works nicely with callbacks that requires some arguments. For example:

```
scheduleCallback(std::function<void(int, bool)> callback);

class MyClass
{

void test()
{
    ...
    scheduleCallback(weak_function(weak_from_this(), &MyClass::someFunction));
}
void someFunction(int, bool);
}
```

How can I update the `weak_function` wrapper so that it could accept arguments after member function pointer for the callback (similar to std::bind)?

For example:

```
scheduleCallback(std::function<void()> callback);

class MyClass
{

void test()
{
    ...
    // I want to make this work: scheduleCallback(weak_function(weak_from_this(), &MyClass::someFunction, 1, false));

    // above should be equivalent to this:
    int arg1 = 1;
    boo arg2 = false;
    scheduleCallback([weakPtr{weak_from_this()}, arg1, arg2](){
        if (auto sharedPtr = weakPtr.lock())
            sharedPtr->someFunction(arg1, arg2);
    });
}
void someFunction(int, bool);
}
```

In other words, I'd need to write such `weak_function` template so that extra args after member function pointer would be bound to the callback and the rest of the args would be passed by the callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like:

```
template<typename C, typename... Args, typename... ExtraArgs>
constexpr auto weak_function(std::weak_ptr<C> weakPtr,
                             void (C::*mf)(Args...),
                             ExtraArgs&&... extraArgs)
{
    return [weakPtr, mf, extraArgs...](auto&&... args) {
        if (auto ptr = weakPtr.lock())
            ((*ptr).*mf)(extraArgs..., std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
}
```

Not sure about `std::forward`/`std::move` with function which might be called several time though.

Comment: The problem here is the return type: it's `std::function<void(Args...)>`, but it basically has to be `Args...` with `Ts...` removed on the right.

Comment: Replaced by `auto` for simplicity :-) We can have utility to have correct `std::function` signature if required.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've "loaded" too much onto your callback generator. I suggest a separation of concerns. Write something like:

```
template<typename C, typename F>
auto weak_function(std::weak_ptr<C> weakPtr, F f)
{
    return [weakPtr, mf]() {
        if (auto ptr = weakPtr.lock())
            return f(*ptr);
    };
}
```

This takes care of your weak pointer trouble.

Now, if you still feel you need to build a function which calls an arbitrary member pointer, you can write it separately; or write another transformer, e.g. something like

```
template<typename C, typename F, typename ... Args>
auto i_like_members(void (C::*mf)(Args...), Args&&... args)
{
    return [mf](C* ptr) {
      return (*ptr).*mf(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
}
```

This will mean, in particular, that you will only  use a single variant of your `scheduleCallback()` function - the one which takes a function with no arguments. And, in fact, I believe you should probably be able to pry that one open as well and avoid building an `std::function`.

Comment: The idea is to have std::thread-like interface that also accepts weak_pointer and locks them before execution. For example: `std::thread th(&MyClass::someFunction, shared_from_this(), arg1, arg2);`. It's a common pattern (at least in my work) to use weak_ptr and lock it before calling `someFunction`. So, it would be nice to do `std::thread th(&MyClass::someFunction, weak_from_this(), arg1, arg2);`. `weak_function` effectively returns regular std::function and adds that weak->shared conversion under the hood.

Comment: With the accepted answer I can simply do it this way: `std::thread th(weak_function( weak_from_this(), &MyClass::someFunction, arg1, arg2));`. I'll need to reorder the args to match interface of std::thread though